# UIDevice batteryLevel method gives wrong value of battery in background?

Tags: ios, ios7, uidevice

My application supports background mode [location service], in background application will continuously communicate with Web-server and it will send device battery with other details.

I found that when application is in background at that time  batteryLevel method is not giving correct value for the battery. It gives last value which it returned when application was in foreground.

For Ex.
batteryLevel method was giving 0.4 value when application was in foreground. After it I put application is background now device shows that battery is 50% but still batteryLevel returns 0.4 value.

Comment: isn't it the case that the battery level is between 0.0-1.0 and the value is somehow in one case rounded to 0.4 in the other case it is rounded to 50% (=0.5)? I mean in a scale where the values representing only (0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0) 0.4 would appear as 0.5

Comment: If value is above 48% method would give 0.5 as a value. but here it was giving 0.4 only. Even for 60% I was getting 0.4.

Comment: Interesting, well, sadly this was my best shot, so did I reacted in comment. I am pretty sure the direct sensor data is more or equally accurate than a displayed value on main screen. Anyways the question would worth a +1 from me. It is interesting to know how it functions in iOS.